# ¿Cómo obtener el ancho de banda entre clietne y servidor?

Tags: c++, rendimiento

Tengo un servidor Express y un cliente C++, necesito saber tanto latencia como ancho de banda entre ellos. Actualmente tengo la latencia:

```
#include <Poco/Net/ICMPClient.h>
#include <Poco/Net/IPAddress.h>
#include <Poco/Net/ICMPEventArgs.h>
#include <Poco/Delegate.h>
#include <iostream>

using Poco::Net::ICMPClient;
using Poco::Net::IPAddress;
using Poco::Net::ICMPEventArgs;
using namespace std;

class PingExample {
public:
PingExample():
    _icmpClient(IPAddress::IPv4)
{
    _icmpClient.pingError += Poco::delegate(this, &PingExample::onError);
    _icmpClient.pingEnd   += Poco::delegate(this, &PingExample::onEnd);
}


void start_ping(const string& host)
{
    _icmpClient.ping(host);
    _icmpClient.pingEnd;
}

void onError(const void* pSender, ICMPEventArgs& args)
{
    cout << args.error();
}

void onEnd(const void* pSender, ICMPEventArgs& args)
{
    cout <<"Average=" << args.avgRTT() << "ms" << endl;
}

private:
       ICMPClient  _icmpClient;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PingExample p;
    while (true){
        p.start_ping("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alguna idea para obtener el ancho de banda? No es necesario que sea con Poco.

Con ancho de banda me refiero a la velocidad de descarga y de subida, como en un test de velocidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el ancho de banda... podrías "ver" en este enlace:
[speedtest - código fuente](https://github.com/librespeed/speedtest)
Y en este otro también:
[speedtest - línea de comandos - código fuente](https://github.com/librespeed/speedtest-cli)
Con esos progs. te pueden ayudar y orientar un poco más a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias!! Creo que eso si que me puede servir